# How to get the array with the same address by storing it in the [NSKeyedArchiver archivedDataWithRootObject:?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uinavigationcontroller, nsuserdefaults, nskeyedarchiver

I store a navigationController in the data with `[NSKeyedArchiver archivedDataWithRootObject:]` and I would like to get it when I want in the app. My problem is that when I call it with the `NSKeyedUnarchiver`, I don't have the good address. How to get the good one?

Address before storing: (UINavigationController *) $0 = 0x00007f956e079200

```
NSData *data = [NSKeyedArchiver archivedDataWithRootObject:self.navigationController];
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:data forKey:@"navigationController"];

NSData *data2 = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] valueForKey:@"navigationController"];
[NSKeyedUnarchiver unarchiveObjectWithData:data2];
```

Address when retrieving: (UINavigationController *) $1 = 0x00007f956e0a8a00

I would like to store the (UINavigationController *) $0 = 0x00007f956e079200 to get it when I want in my app.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please explain _why_ this is important to you...

Comment: @Alladinian Because sometimes, I am in classes that doesn't see the navigationcontrollers, and I need to update some spinners, or things like that. If I can store it in the [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults], it should be very easy

Comment: When you do `unarchiveObjectWithData` it create new object with new address, not the old one

Answer (score 0):

**Do not do so.** Do not store memory addresses in some kind of database and try to resolve them some time in the future, this is absolutly non-reliable.

Instead, you should store the *model data* (e.g. spinner state etc.) somewhere, and add and subscribe to notifications (check `NSNotificationCenter`) to update the view when the model changes.